# jQuery Load Callback in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, callback, load

I have a problem with IE7 and the Callback of jQuery Load.
All browsers exept IE7 fire the Callback of my Load function correctly. Just can't figure out a solution for that.

```
$('#cd_vk_cinemascreen').load('/index.php?id=19 #cd_content', function() {
 $('#cd_vk_cinemascreen #cd_content').attr('class', 'cm_contentWrapper');
 $('#cd_vk_cinemascreen #cd_content').attr('id', 'nothing');
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any error messages? Your question is a little vague.

Comment: You're performing a selector query for the exact same DOM element in two consecutive statements. How is it possible that you don't see that this is redundant?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no error messages... :(
Whats the problem of selecting the same element in two consecutive statements?

Comment: @user983992 It's like going to the store to by two packs of cigarettes but doing it in a manner where you go to the store, buy one pack, then come back home, then go back to the store and buy the second pack. This is of course inefficient, I'm sure that you understand.

Comment: Ok thx, then how do i set the id and the class attributes by only selecting the element once?

.attr().attr() ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently; I *believe* (but am not certain) it is a race condition.

When using jQuery `.load` with document fragments (`'/index.php?id=19 #cd_content'` in your case), the entire document is acquired using AJAX. It seems that at that point, the callback is launched *at the same time* that the AJAX-loaded document is parsed, the desired selector block is extracted and parsed out, and the ID is added to your own document.

But by the time that block is parsed out and added to your document, the callback has already started running. That callback has done nothing, of course, because at the time it is run the element it is selecting hasn't been inserted yet.

My solution was to avoid the problem: I trimmed down the AJAX-loaded document so that I didn't need to load a fragment, thus avoiding the race condition.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to trim the Ajax-loaded document. I think I'll try to load the contents with $.ajax()

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$( cinemascr ).load( '/index.php?id=19 #cd_content', function () {
    $( '#cd_content', cinemascr ).
        addClass( 'cm_contentWrapper' ).
        [0].id = 'nothing';
});
```

where `cinemascr` is cached beforehand - I assume it's a static element on the page. In that case you can cache it on page load like so:

```
var cinemascr = $( '#cd_vk_cinemascreen' )[0];
```

It could be that IE7 doesn't like the format of the URL `'/index.php?id=19'`...

Comment: Tried the realURL which looks like "/page1/page2". Didn't solve the Problem. I'll try to load the contents with $.ajax().